Best way to find tomcat directory in linux
What is the best way to find tomcat directory path on a Linux machine if tomcat is not running? I have multiple instances of tomcat.
I am running locate tomcat | grep -i "[t]omcat", is there any other way given that tomcat isn't running?

Have you tried grep CATALINA_BASE /etc/tomcat*/tomcat.conf? The location may change depending on how you installed tomcat.

Need to find in whatever location tomcat is installed in, so location path is not an option

If you have a completely arbitrary install location then you're probably stuck with find / -name \*tomcat\*. Hopefully you don't have a large number of network drives attached. On a small-ish system this might take an hour or so. On large systems, maybe a few days. Have you tried asking the person who installed tomcat where they put it? Also, the path of the configuration file can be completely independent of the executable path or the application path. Which of the three do you want?

right now all i want is to find tomcat path for my ansible playbook irrespective of timcat running. i can run ps to find running process and gather all -D tomcat info but when tomcat isn;t running  i should be able to query and fine catalina base and home and logging properties

@doneal24 surely you want -type d there, right?

@terdon Probably, but I wanted to catch tomcat.conf and/or tomcat.service. At the time of my comment, the OP was unclear as to what he was looking for and why.
